# Unit Testing - Mock Methods within Methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing

I am writing unit tests for a Node.js application, and I am wondering if I am mocking the correct parts of the code.

The example below is a hypothetical class that has two static methods.

The method `isTokenValid` calls another method, `decodeToken` which takes the token and a callback. The callback is defined inside of `isTokenValid`. Both these methods belong to the same class.

When unit testing `isTokenValid` my approach is to mock the `decodeToken` method.

It is clear to me that when unit testing, dependencies such AJAX requests should be mocked. However, does that also hold true for this type of dependency or am I being too granular?

Is mocking `decodeToken` the right approach to unit testing `isTokenValid`?

```
var TokenClass = {};

TokenClass.isTokenValid(token) {
    TokenClass.decodeToken(token, function(err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('There was a validation error');
            }
            if (decoded) {
                return true
            };
        }
    }

    TokenClass.decodeToken(token, callback) {
        // some logic here to decode token
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }
        // if token is not valid
        if (!validToken) {
            return callback(null, undefined);
        }
        // if token is valid
        return callback(null, decoded);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches.

In classic unit tests you can mock everything that is external to your tested unit - in this case `isTokenValid` method is your unit. But that approach isn't practical.

The best way is to mock things that doesn't let your tests run in isolation and in deterministic way (same result every time).

If `decodeToken` is not calling any external resource (url, database, file system) then you don't have to mock that out. However if it does call external resource, then `decodeToken` should be implemented in another object, i.e. `TokenDecoder` and injected into `TokenValidator`, then for unit test of `TokenValidator` you can inject mocked `TokenDecoder` that is not calling any external resource.

`TokenDecoder` then should be tested using integration test, but that is another topic.